# Double single-side border of different colors on an HTML table row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table, and I want some of the rows to have 2 different colored 35px borders, kind of like this:

[image: Multicolor Double Border Example].

Please let me know if you know of a way to do this, all of the pots that I've seen online only tell you how to make a multicolored four sided border and I have not figured out how to modify those solutions to only apply to one edge.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please also show what these other posts mention; it could be just a matter of changing the rules to use `border-left` instead of `border`...

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to wrap the table in a `<div>` and apply a left margin and a negative box-shadow.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .outer {
            padding-top: 35px;
            margin-left: 35px;
            box-shadow: -35px 0 0 rgba(0,0,128,0.8)
        }
        .outer table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .outer th, .outer td {
            padding: 3px;
        }
        .ltBlue {
            background-color:cornflowerblue;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
        .outer tr td:first-child {
            width: 35px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .outer tr td:nth-child(5) {
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
```

and...

```
    <div class="outer">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="ltBlue">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="ltBlue" colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">Overdue Books</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ltBlue">&nbsp;</td>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Due</th>
                <th>Fine</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ltBlue">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>01/20/2018</td>
                <td>Goodnight Moon</td>
                <td>01/14/2018</td>
                <td>$6.34</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="ltBlue">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>01/20/2018</td>
                <td>Goodnight Moon</td>
                <td>01/14/2018</td>
                <td>$6.34</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you where you want.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
  <div id="table_2_border" style="width:300px;border-left:1px solid orange;border-top:1px solid black;border-right:1px solid pink;border-bottom:1px solid yellow">
  <table style="width:295px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;border-left:1px solid green;border-top:1px solid blue;border-right:1px solid yellow;border-bottom:1px solid red">
            <tr>
                <th style="border-left:1px solid green;border-bottom:1px solid pink">One</th>
                <th style="border-left:1px solid red;">Two</th>
                <th style="border-left:1px solid blue;">Three</th>
                <th style="border-left:1px solid orange;">Four</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>One info</td>
                <td>Two info</td>
                <td>Three info</td>
                <td>Four info</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, you can style each section to the color of your choice.